# Problems with setting the dataType in the dBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

Whenever I try to choose a data type for any column I get this message. I don't type by myself but choose from drop-down menu instead. 
Details message as follows,

```
Error setting property 'dataType' value
Bad data type name specified: serial
```

it can be any type instead of serial, the result message will be the same.
The database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: update to latest version and work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem :(

Dbeaver 5.2.5, Fedora 29, PostgreSQL 9.6